# How can I search/filter 2 MySQL tables using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question on how to search 2 MySQL database tables using PHP. I was able to display and search one table as shown below. How can I update this code to search in both tables using the LIKE statement? Thank you!!

Table1 Name: SM
Fields: SN, Time, Date

Table2 name: info
Fields: firstname, lastname, username

The code is the following:

```
 <?php
      session_start();

      if(isset($_POST['search']))
      {  $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];
         $query = "SELECT * FROM `SM` WHERE CONCAT(`SN`, `Time`, `Date` LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
         $search_result = filterTable($query)
      }
      else{
          $query = "SELECT * FROM `SM`";
          $search_result = filterTable($query);
          }
      function filterTable($query)
      {
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "Login");
        $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
        return $filter_Result;
       }

    ?>
```

Comment: You will need to perform 2 selects. You can't search 2 unrelated tables in a single query.

Comment: you can join tables and make your query temporary table for search both tables..

Comment: First query has syntax error as `CONCAT` does not close. And you really should use parameterization (even sanitize) since search params derive from web post.